# Обработка отсутствия ответа на викторину в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота для создания и проведения викторин с помощью библиотеки aiogram.
Суть проблемы в следующем: бот присылает викторину пользователю:

```
await bot.send_poll(call.from_user.id, 
                    question='2+2', 
                    options=[3, 4], 
                    is_anonymous=False, 
                    type=PollType.QUIZ,
                    correct_option_id=1,
                    explanation=None,
                    open_period=10
                    )
```

Затем ждет ответа

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def get_user_answer_and_send_new_poll(poll_answer: types.PollAnswer):
    # Здесь проверяет правильный ли ответ, заносит в табличку, а затем здесь же отправляет следующий вопрос
    await bot.send_poll(poll_answer.user.id, 
                    question='3+3', 
                    options=[5, 6], 
                    is_anonymous=False, 
                    type=PollType.QUIZ,
                    correct_option_id=1,
                    explanation=None,
                    open_period=10
                    )
    pass
```

При ответах на вопросы всё работает замечательно. Но дело в том, что если этот `open_period=10` закончится, то бот ничего не отправит. Была мысль попробовать через `@dp.poll_handler(lambda active_quiz: active_quiz.is_closed is True)`, но не совсем понял, как это работает. И здесь тоже возникает вопрос, как мне отправить новый вопрос человеку, если я не знаю, как взять его user_id? Через callback, message, poll_answer это можно легко сделать, но если человек ничего не ответил..

Хотелось бы отследить отсутствие ответа на вопрос и сразу же отправить новый.
Прошу помощи в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Так как сохраняю промежуточные ответы в словаре, где ключ - это id пользователя, а значение - это класс, в который записываются количество правильных ответов, добавил туда текущий на данный момент вопрос, который переключается, когда игрок отвечает на вопрос или время вопроса истекло. Вот сам словарь и пример класса:

```
users = {}

class User():
    def __init__(self, correct_answers=0, current_question=1):
        self.correct_answers = correct_answers
        self.current_question = current_question
```

Когда отправляю пользователю первый вопрос, сохраняю его в `users`:

```
users[call.from_user.id] = User()
```

Теперь в функцию, отправляющую вопрос, добавляю следующий код:

```
time_to_answer = 10
await bot.send_poll(call.from_user.id, 
                    question='2+2', 
                    options=[3, 4], 
                    is_anonymous=False, 
                    type=PollType.QUIZ,
                    correct_option_id=1,
                    explanation=None,
                    open_period=time_to_answer
                    )

await asyncio.sleep(time_to_answer)
user: User = users.get(call.from_user.id)
current_question = user.current_question
if current_question == 1:
    user.current_question += 1
    # А здесь отправляем новый вопрос
    await send_question(user, call.from_user.id, user.current_question)
```

Сама функция для отправки вопроса:

```
async def send_question(user: User, user_id: int, current_question: int):

    # Здесь отправляем новый вопрос

    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    user: User = users.get(call.from_user.id)
    user_current_question = user.current_question
    if user_current_question == current_question:
        user.current_question += 1
        # Cнова отправляем новый вопрос
        await send_question(user, call.from_user.id, user.current_question)
```

И вот хэндлер, принимающий ответы пользователей:

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def get_user_answer_and_send_new_poll(poll_answer: types.PollAnswer):
    user: UserPlayInQuiz = users_base.get(poll_answer.user.id)
    # Здесь проверяет правильный ли ответ, заносит в табличку, а затем здесь же отправляет следующий вопрос
    user.current_question += 1
    await send_question(user, poll_answer.user.id, user.current_question)
```